# Split String on tags into multiple Textboxes

Tags: string, windows-phone-7, textblock

I do not knot where to search anymore for a solution.

I have a string which contains tags `"< p >"` and "< /p >", as well as "< h1>" and "< /h1>" for headers, and "< a>< /a>" for links. The string is passed via app.current to a second page, when i set it as source of a textblock I see my whole string.

Now my Problem:
I want to create a new TextBlock on every "< p>", which contains the text until "< /p>". Same for the headers, as I want to style them differently. The links I want to see in a list.

I tried several things, but found no working solution. My last try was to work with this http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2011/04/binding-text-containing-tags-to-textblock-inlines-using-attached-property-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7/. I was not able to change this for my needs.

I wanted to create substrings from my string, and for each substring a new run with/or a new TextBlock. Did not figure it out.

I really do not have any ideas left for this. Anyone any idea?

Comment: Could you use a WebBrowser control?

Comment: I pass the string from one page to another, and want to avoid another we request for app performance...

Comment: ok, I was able to split the text with a combination of String.Split and Regex.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(yourString);

string header = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("h1").InnerText;

List<string> paragraphs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("p")
    .Select(p => p.InnerText).ToList();
```

The simplest way to get HtmlAgilityPack for WP7 is to install [NuGet](http://nuget.org), right click your `References` and select "Manage NuGet Packages" and then search "Online" for `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Comment: Hi, I managed to install the pack. The SelectSingleNode and SelectNodes are not regocnized by the HtmlAgilityPack. I manually added the references included on the 94773-version, but it says I am missing a reference or a using statement. What am I missing?

Comment: @MSicc - The `Select*` methods are on `HtmlDocument.DocumentNode`, not on `HtmlDocument` itself. I've updated the code. You should be able to revert back to the NuGet version.

Comment: ok, this works now. thanks for clearing up. I tried now to convert all entries of the List paragraphs into textblocks, but I cannot use foreach in this state. how can I convert this now?

Comment: ok, wenn i navigate to my second page i get on every Listcreation an NullArgumentException which I cannot solve

Comment: @MSicc - I think we might be creeping beyond the scope of the original question, but we'll see what we can do. When debugging, what exact line is throwing the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: List<string> paragraphs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("p")
    .Select(p => p.InnerText).ToList(); throws it. wenn i bind the passed string to a TextBox, it is shown without an error but with the tags, so the passing works. Details: System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  Message=Value can not be null.
Parameter name: source   StackTrace:   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Select[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector). with try/catch the error shows not up, but the text is not shown.

Comment: @MSicc - It looks like `SelectNodes` is returning `null` in some cases (possibly when they're are no `p` elements). You'll need to check the return value is not null before you perform the `Select`.

Comment: sorry, but I could not get rid of that ArgumentNullException, no matter what I tried. I now have a combination of String.Split and Regex. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To expand slightly on Richard Szalay's answer, the version of the HTML Agility Pack on NuGet doesn't seem to include the WP7 specific implementation that was added.  In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738181/convert-html-to-xml-with-wp7) there is a reference to the HAPPhone version which can be downloaded from the [HTML AGility Pack project page](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/77494#), and works very well on the phone.

Unfortunately, you'll have to download the source and build it yourself / add the reference manually.  I guess the NuGet version will be updated in time, but when I did this last week it was the only way.

Comment: The NuGet package actually does include both a `sl3-wp` and a `sl4-windowsphone71`, so WP7 support is definitely there.

Comment: Maybe I managed to get the wrong version.  Thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it seems that with the nuget package it isn't included. Or I am missing simply a reference/using statement... Will have to dive in deeper